# Google Maps markers not removing iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm running a thread to fetch drivers location every 10 seconds and want to remove the added markers from the map but it doesn't work..

**My code:**

```
-(void)APiResponse:(id)returnJson
{        
        [googleMapsDriverPin setMap:nil];
        googleMapsDriverPin = nil;

        NSMutableArray *driverPins = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int x = 0; x < [[returnJson valueForKey:@"drivers"] count]; x++) {
            CLLocation *driverLocations = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[[[returnJson valueForKey:@"drivers"] objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"driver_latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[[[detail valueForKey:@"drivers"] objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"driver_longitude"] doubleValue]];
            [driverPins addObject:driverLocations];
        }

        for (CLLocation *newLocation in driverPins) {
            googleMapsDriverPin = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            [googleMapsDriverPin setPosition:newLocation.coordinate];
            [googleMapsDriverPin setAnimated:YES];
            [googleMapsDriverPin setTitle:@"title"];
            [googleMapsDriverPin setSnippet:@"snippet"];
            [googleMapsDriverPin setIcon:[GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];
            [googleMapsDriverPin setMap:googleMaps];
         }
}
```

It just keeps adding and adding every 10 seconds and not removing, please help!
Thanks!

Comment: when working with MKMapView you can use `[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]` for removing all the pins

Comment: try [mapView clear]; (where mapView is your GMSMapView); ..or.. [googleMaps clear]; if googleMaps is your GMSMapView

Comment: @TonyMkenu Thanks for the answer, the thing is, these markers are the drivers, I would like to keep MY CURRENT POSITION marker on the map as well, and if I clear the map it clears all the markers, I just want to update the drivers locations every 10 seconds.. :( Tried adding my current location afterwards, but only displays the marker when it wants to? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a kind of quick and dirty option but if you wanted to go that way GMSMarker has a userData property which you could use to tag the driver pins

```
- (void)apiResponse:(id)returnJson
{        
    for (GMSMarker *pin in self.googleMaps.markers) {
        if (pin.userData == @"Driver Pin"){ 
            pin.map = nil; 
        }
    }

    ...

    for (CLLocation *newLocation in driverPins) {
        googleMapsDriverPin = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        ...
        [googleMapsDriverPin setUserData:@"Driver Pin"];
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
[self.googleMapsView clear];
```

Comment: the point is that he doesn't have the array in the first place

Comment: This works 100% ! Thank you so much! I didn't know about the userData, it might come in handy next time! Thanks for all answers, but this is best :)

Answer (score 2):

On the based on pin id you can also delete pin.
Here deletePinId integer is for selected pin id.

```
for(GMSMarker *pin in self.mapView_.markers) {
NSLog(@"pin.userData : %@",pin.userData);
int pinId1 = [[pin.userData valueForKey:@"pin_id"] integerValue];
if(deltePinId == pinId1 ){
    pin.map = nil;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you currently only store ONE marker, but you want to add N markers -- so (as saxon said) you need an array to hold all the pins :)

```
@interface YouClass

...

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *googleMapsDriverPins;
@end

@implementation YourClass

...

-(void)APiResponse:(id)returnJson
{    
    for(GMSMarker *pin in self.googleMapsDriverPins) {
        pin.map = nil;
    }    
    self.googleMapsDriverPins = nil;

    NSMutableArray *driverPins = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int x = 0; x < [[returnJson valueForKey:@"drivers"] count]; x++) {
        CLLocation *driverLocations = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[[[returnJson valueForKey:@"drivers"] objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"driver_latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[[[detail valueForKey:@"drivers"] objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"driver_longitude"] doubleValue]];
        [driverPins addObject:driverLocations];
    }

    self.googleMapsDriverPins = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:driverPins.count];
    for (CLLocation *newLocation in driverPins) {
        GMSMarker *googleMapsDriverPin = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        [googleMapsDriverPin setPosition:newLocation.coordinate];
        [googleMapsDriverPin setAnimated:YES];
        [googleMapsDriverPin setTitle:@"title"];
        [googleMapsDriverPin setSnippet:@"snippet"];
        [googleMapsDriverPin setIcon:[GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];
        [googleMapsDriverPin setMap:googleMaps];
        [self.googleMapsDriverPins addObject:googleMapsDriverPin];
     }
 }
 @end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but getting warning sign: "Collection expression type 'GMSMarker *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'" ...guess it means it can't loop if its just 1 object maybe?

Comment: it means i missed an s somewhere  OR it means you copied it wrong ;) ... the error says you try to enum over a GMSMarker NOT over an Array containing 0-n GMSMarkers, obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: self.googleMapDriverPins = self.googleMapsDriverPins :) (BTW: I wrote it inline of course so there may of course be typos)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a loop adding multiple drivers, each of which assigns to the member variable `googleMapsDriverPin`. Then next time it removes the `googleMapsDriverPin` - but that will only be the last pin you added, not all of them.

For this to work you would need to add each marker inside your loop to an array, and then remove all of them from the map on your next update.

Comment: I did try to remove them, but it's not working: [googleMapsDriverPin setMap:nil]; googleMapsDriverPin = nil;

Comment: That will only remove the last one, not all of them.

Comment: ..you're right! Only removes last one! So what other way can I add an array of markers to be able to remove them ALL on next update? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2:

Create an outlet for your map:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
```

Create an array to store all markers

```
var markers = [GMSMarker]()
```

Create markers like this:

```
    func funcName() {    
        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

        for pin: GMSMarker in self.markers {
             if pin.userData as! String == "from" {
                   pin.map = nil
             }
        }

        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "navigation-red")
        marker.userData = "from"
        marker.map = self.mapView
        self.markers.append(marker)
    }
```

You can set the userData property to anything you want and later on use that string to delete that marker.When the funcName function is executed, all markers with userData as "from" are removed from the map.Let me know if you have any queries.